# PLSQL - Searching for record in a Nested Table that was Bulk Collected

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I used  `bulk collect` to fetch records into a nested table.  I want to search for a record with `exists` method but it's not working out. I then found out the `exists` method uses index and does not look for the values.  Do I need to go across each record and search for a match?  Is there a shorter way to do it because I am going to use the same logic for large set of records?

I read in websites that `bulk collect` doesn't work properly with an associative array when using a varchar as a key so I used nested tables instead.  Also, I don't want to read each record and store it in a hashmap as it degrades performance.

```
Create table sales(
   name varchar2(100)
)
insert into sales(name) values('Test');
insert into sales(name) values('alpha');
insert into sales(name) values(null);


declare
 type sales_tab is table of varchar2(1000);
 t_sal sales_tab;
 begin
 select name bulk collect into t_sal from sales;


 if(t_sal.exists('Test')) THEN
   dbms_output.put_line('Test exists');
 END IF;

 dbms_output.put_line(t_sal.count);
end;
```

Comment: why not just add a WHERE clause to the query? that'll make it both faster and use less memory.

Comment: Cant use where clause because it takes lot of time when i go with large data even when i have index on it.

Comment: "Can't"? If it's a query performance issue then I'm almost 100% certain that doing the filtering in PL/SQL will not make it any faster.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Will try to check the where clause again.  Might be I overlooked the sql query performance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`exists()` function tells you if a particular element with integer or varchar2(for associative arrays index by varchar2 collections ) index of a collection exists. It does not test for membership. To be able to check if a collection contains an element with specific value `member of` condition can be used:

```
SQL> declare
  2    type  sales_tab is table of varchar2(1000);
  3    t_sal sales_tab;
  4  begin
  5   select name
  6     bulk collect into t_sal
  7     from sales;
  8  
  9   if('Test' member of t_sal) THEN
 10     dbms_output.put_line('Test exists');
 11   END IF;
 12  
 13   dbms_output.put_line(t_sal.count);
 14  end;
 15  /
Test exists
3
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.  It's a great help.  How can i check for duplicate key members.  If i want to know if there are more than one 'Test' then i want to do a logic based on it.

Comment: @Arav It's getting deeper. Depending on your final goal you have to ask yourself do you really need a procedural processing for that? As Jeffrey Kemp said in the comment to your question, wouldn't it be better to use plain SQL, it would be also simpler to test for duplicates?

Comment: Thanks a lot. Will try to check the sql query again. Might be I overlooked the sql query performance.